# Django - What happens when you delete an entity in a table that has a foreign key ManyToMany relationship to another?

Tags: django

I've noticed that Django doesn't let you set the `on_delete` parameter for `ManyToManyField`. This made me curious what happens if you delete an entity in a ManyToMany relationship? So for example, let's say we have `Book`, which has a ManyToMany relationship to `Author`. Let's say that a book A has 3 authors: "Tom Lam", "Lam Tom" and "Britney Britney". Then let's say "Britney Britney" gets deleted from the `Author` table. Does "Britney Britney" get removed from the ManyToMany relationship with `Book`? Does an exception get thrown when trying to delete "Britney Britney?" **What does Django do in the case that an entity is deleted when it exists in a ManyToMany relationship?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Britney Britney" is deleted from the `Author` table, "Britney Britney" is also removed from the book authors (this also applies in reverse). Django does not throw an exception, simply the deleted instance will no longer be accessible through the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: is this potentially costly time wise? Or since it's FK are indexed is this very quick? Even if the entity being deleted is in a lot of entity many-to-many relations.

Comment: @user8714896 I think the process is fast, except in the case where a very large number of entities are involved, plus it depends on how often this event happens.